# number input is taking the placeholder string as the value

Tags: html, forms, angular, angular-forms

Here i have a form input of type `number` but whenever the form is submitted, without inputting any number, It choses the placeholder text of "rating" as the value. how do i prevent it.

I want the input number field to be invalid if theres no input in the input field

Here is all the form

```
   <section class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Add Movies</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="movie-name" placeholder="Enter the Movie Name" ngModel name="movieName" required
            #name="ngModel" [ngClass]="{isValid: name.valid && name.touched, isInvalid: !name.valid && name.touched}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-1">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" name="rating" min="1" max="5" placeholder="Rating" size="15" ngModel="rating" required 
            #rating="ngModel" [ngClass]="{isValid: rating.valid && rating.touched, isInvalid: !rating.valid && rating.touched}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="release-date" placeholder="Release Date" ngModel name="releaseDate" required 
          #releaseDate="ngModel" [ngClass]="{isValid: releaseDate.valid && releaseDate.touched, isInvalid: !releaseDate.valid && releaseDate.touched}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="movie-description" placeholder="Enter the description of the Movie" ngModel name="movieDescription"
            required #description="ngModel" [ngClass]="{isValid: description.valid && description.touched, isInvalid: !description.valid && description.touched}">
        </div>
        <p class="help-block alert alert-info text-center">By submitting the data, you agree to our Terms and that you have read our Data Use Policy, including our Cookie Use.
        </p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block" [disabled]="!f.valid">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you give all your form? Because if it is Reactive Forms or not, this is not the same answer. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use 2 ways bindings? [(ngModel)]="rating"

Comment: how can you please write an answer with that

Comment: Edit replace [ngModel]="rating" by [ngModel]="rating"

Comment: its a template driven form and to register the control you need to add ngModel attribute without the brackets

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

`<input type="number" class="form-control" name="rating" min="1" max="5" placeholder="Rating" [(ngModel)]="yourmodelfield" required [ngClass]="{isValid: rating.valid && rating.touched, isInvalid: !rating.valid && rating.touched}">`

using [Two way data binding](https://angular.io/guide/forms#two-way-data-binding-with-ngmodel)

Comment: what should i set yourmodelfield to. coz i want the placeholder text to appear

Comment: The placeholder appears, as placeholder="Rating" remains. *yourmodelfield* is simply the variable bound to the input, so if you have a variable called "rating" in your component, just type "rating"

Comment: I didnt understand. can you please show it in plunkr.

Comment: However, the link I posted is really clear.. have a look

Comment: and is using a pattern a better way than two way binding

Comment: answer please ?

Comment: Patterns are used as regular expressions to place conditions on input. Two way binding is totally different, and it's used to bind the data between model and view. Please have a look at what I've linked. I think Angular official documentation is clearer than me